# Start VScode with named terminals and command ready to start

Tags: web, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Everytime I open my vsCode project with multiple projects inside, I need to open multiple terminals and use the command "yarn <project_name>:start". I also rename them with the project name because they all have the name name by default (powershell in my case, then node when the command is launched).

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to open a predefined list of terminals with a predefined name for each project.
2. Is there a way to input the command in each terminal with or without lauching the command.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: have you read the `runOptions` of tasks, tasks can create terminals, in the terminal profile you might set a command to execute

Comment: Based on your hint, I read more carrefully the tasks documentation [tasks documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks). 

Then I found this [blog post](https://sdivakarrajesh.medium.com/automating-task-to-run-on-startup-in-vscode-fe30d7f99454#:~:text=Open%20the%20command%20palette%20with,the%20tasks%20should%20start%20running) which essentially explains what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using vscode tasks, I was able to add 2 tasks and call them together in another tasks that activates automatically on everytime I open the workspace.

```
{
    "label": "Start Dev",
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    },
    "dependsOn": ["Common", "Hub"]
},
{
    "label": "Common",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "yarn dev:common",
    "windows": {
        "command": "yarn dev:common"
    },
    "group": "none",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
    }
},
{
    "label": "Hub",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "yarn dev:hub",
    "windows": {
        "command": "yarn dev:hub"
    },
    "group": "none",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new"
    }
}
```

Comment: why specify an identical command for windows

Comment: Good question, I simply followed what was in the blog post. I removed them and it still works. I am new to Stackoverflow, should I edit my answer?